# Backup cd as image or copy files

Tags: backup, iso-image, compact-disc, disk-image

I have some old music CDs and I want to backup them before they stop working completely.

I know how to backup them technically but I am not sure whether to backup them as images or copy the music files to hard drive.

Comment: Well, do you want to be able to listen to the music while it's backed up? Do you want to be able to put them somewhere else, or only back on a CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 'real' music CDs ([CD-DA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-DA)) you can't just copy the files. There are no files, or if there are, they don't contain the real data.

I recommend you rip the CD (i.e. converting the audio data to real files) and use a lossless audio codec for this. FLAC is a very good one. This way you don't loose any quality compared to the CD and still get a good compression rate.

Comment: It seems like it is real cd. There is only some player and no visible audio data.

Comment: Just wanted to add there is a list of lossless audio format as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless#Audio .

Comment: FLAC is good choice for me as I prefer free & open source solutions.